# How do I get the disk drive serial number in filter driver?

Tags: c, driver, wmi, kernel-mode, filter-driver

I write a driver in windows, and I need disk drive serial number, for user mode I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24049895/5306861) ansver. 
My question is it possible to translate the above code to kernel mode, and how? Is WMI query available in filter driver? Sample code can greatly help.

**EDIT:**

I found [here](http://www.winvistatips.com/threads/smbios-info-from-kernel-mode.178848/) this code, but how I rewrite him for get serial number?

```
void GetSmbios()
{

    NTSTATUS status;
    GUID smbiosGUID = SMBIOS_DATA_GUID; // defined in wmiguid.h
    PVOID wmiObject = NULL;
    PWNODE_ALL_DATA dataBuffer;

    ULONG bufferSize;
    int TAG_SMBIOS = 'smbi';
    //
    // Get a WMI block handle to the SMBIOS_DATA_GUID
    //
    status = IoWMIOpenBlock((GUID *)&smbiosGUID, WMIGUID_QUERY,
        &wmiObject);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) 
    {
        return status;
    }

    //
    // Determine how much space is required for the data
    //
    status = IoWMIQueryAllData(wmiObject, &bufferSize, NULL);
    if (status != STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL) 
    {
        ObDereferenceObject(wmiObject);
        return status;
    }

    //
    // Allocate the necessary storage. This space must come out of NP-pool
    //
    dataBuffer = ExAllocatePoolWithTag(
        NonPagedPool,
        bufferSize,
        TAG_SMBIOS);

    if (dataBuffer == NULL) 
    {
        ObDereferenceObject(wmiObject);
        return STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After allocating memory, I believe you need to call `IoWMIQueryAllData()` again, this time passing dataBuffer.

SMBIOS doesn't seem related to disk drives, so you'll want a different GUID to pass to `IoWMIOpenBlock()`.  Perhaps [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394346(v=vs.85).aspx) (`{BF253431-1E4D-4F57-00E7-64B2CACC801E}`), since your user-mode example and [others](https://superuser.com/questions/708146/how-to-get-the-hard-drive-serial-number) query Win32_PhysicalMedia to get SerialNumber.

However, [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2697022) references a (presumably user-mode) DLL that is the provider for Win32_PhysicalMedia.  So this may not be accessible in kernel-mode.

But it also gives a hint how to get the information from kernel-mode: IOCTLs.  It mentions IOCTL_SMART_GET_VERSION, which should be just SMART_GET_VERSION, and [here's an example](http://forum.sysinternals.com/sata-drive-serial-number_topic6643_page2.html):
 (in user-mode, but you should be able to do similar from kernel-mode using `ZwDeviceIoControlFile()`).  Note it follows up with another ioctl command, SMART_RCV_DRIVE_DATA, to get the serial number.

Another ioctl that sounds promising (and more general) is IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, with the input STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY.PropertyId set to StorageDeviceProperty, so the output will be a STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR structure, which has field SerialNumberOffset:

> Specifies the byte offset from the beginning of the structure to a null-terminated ASCII string that contains the device's serial number. If the device has no serial number, this member is zero.

Comment: Which worked for you: WMI, SMART_RCV_DRIVE_DATA, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY or something else?

Answer (score 1):

[`FILE_FS_VOLUME_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540287(v=vs.85).aspx) contains field `VolumeSerialNumber`.  This data structure might be retrieved with [`ZwQueryVolumeInformationFile(... FileFsVolumeInformation)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567070(v=vs.85).aspx).

That requires a handle to the volume or a file/directory in the volume.  If that's not feasible, but you have a `DEVICE_OBJECT`, you might try building your own IRP with [`IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549318(v=vs.85).aspx) and sending it with [`IoCallDriver()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548336(v=vs.85).aspx), though I don't know if that's sanctioned -- the docs say such a "request is sent by the I/O Manager."

Comment: I need **disk drive** serial number not **Volume** Serial Number.

Comment: Sorry!  Thought you were being imprecise.

Comment: This really saved the day for me!